# How to show error when document selected different status. Another one is why checkbox not saved

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

**First Question**

I have this three different status. I have a button to do a process to create batch. User need to select document to create the batch.

User will only select documents based on its status and cannot be mixed up. For example, if the status is Not Found, only document with status Not Found can be selected. If user select document with other status, it will show error. Same with status Obsolete and Spoilt.

[image: ONE]

How can prevent user from selecting document with different status and only select document in same status? Thanks!

**Second Question**

I have this document with checkbox options. I then select the checkbox then save. When I open back the document, the checkbox I already select is not saved. Below here the checkbox option.

[image]

Any idea why the checkbox is not saved when we save the document? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In the future, please only ask one question per post. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will first answer your second question:

Your design is flawed and does NOT work like this in Lotus Notes: You always need values to store in a checkbox- field.

Just replace the 5 checkbox- fields by one. In that one just put in the values A,B,C,D,E on the selection Tab (second tab in properties) and set the number of columns to 5 on the same tab. That makes it WAY easier to work with the values and it reduces the amount of fields drastically.

Now to your first question: You cannot prohibit the user from selection documents from different categories, but you can "filter" the selected documents in your script (by checking:

```
If document.FaultyStatus = "Which one?" then
    ....
End If
```

of you could use a Picklist to let the user select just from filtered documents as Umeli stated with NotesUiWorkspace.PicklistCollection( ..... , "Not Found" )

Comment: oh right. so I will just use one checkbox with 5 values which is A B C D E. I will try it. Will get back to you later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You might have a look at `NotesUIWorkspace.picklistCollection` method with the last parameter (`SingleCategory`) set.
2. Did you define some values for the checkboxes ?

Comment: I am sure, there is no value in the checkboxes... as that would be displayed on the screenshot... no value... nothing to save...

Comment: Yes, I think I'm not defining any values in the checkboxes. Will try to change it later. I'll follow torsten step. Thanks!